# Convert FoxPro form to a program file

Tags: forms, visual-foxpro

I have a form and I would like to convert it to a program file 
How can I create a prg file with all the code from a vfp form

Comment: How complex a form, class libraries that controls may come from, etc... I've written my own VFP-based utility to convert .SCX and even .VCX to .PRG files and may offer a conversion for you (no charge).

Comment: Thanks for the offer where can I download it

Comment: Actually, it is a little bit more than what Wilbishardis answered with, and that looks really good... Did you try that option first?

Comment: I tried it and I am getting 2 errors when running one property is read only and one a popup insert object -control type

Comment: I am getting two errors - one a popup asking for control type and one poperties is read only

Comment: where can I get your utilty thanks

Answer (score 2):

From the main VFP IDE menu:

`Tools --> Class Browser`

Click `Open` (the yellow folder icon).

From the `Files of type` drop-down, choose `Form`.

Select the form you wish to open.

In the class browser, click `View Class Code` (fourth icon from the left).

You can copy and paste this into a prg.

Note that the code will not always run as-is, it may need some re-working.